# save R for loop results in different folder

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, lapply

My objective is to apply a set of code to each file in a folder(C:\sample), and then save the processed data into anther folder(C:\cleaned). I learned from other posts here (big thanks!) and wrote a code for my case:

```
files <- list.files(path="C:\\sample", pattern="*.CSV", full.names=T, recursive=FALSE)
datalist <- lapply(files, function(x) {
t <- read.csv(x, header=T, na.string=c("", "null","NaN"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE) # load file
t[ , c(4:10)]<- sapply(t[ , c(4:10)], as.numeric)
t <- t[!is.na(t$Node.1),]
})

for( i in 1:length(files)){
write.csv(datalist[[i]] , files[[i]] ,row.names=F )
}
```

By running my current code, the results will replace the original files in the folder "C:\sample". How can I revise the code a little so each processed file will be saved in another folder "C:\cleaned"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using `full.names=T` will add the path to the filename, which is inconvenient for what you are doing.

The best way to handle the issue is to set your working directory

```
setwd("C:\\sample")
```

Then list your files

```
files <- list.files("C:\\sample", pattern="*.CSV")
```

You can then either append the desired path

```
write.csv(datalist[[i]] , paste0("C:\\cleaned\", files[[i]]), 
          row.names=F)
```

or change the working directory and use directly the filenames

```
setwd("C:\\cleaned")
write.csv(datalist[[i]] , files[[i]], row.names=F)
```

Comment: Thanks. But the output reports error:  Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file 'C:\cleaned\C:\sample/N1_07252014.CSV': Invalid argument